# Echo data from input textbox beside box

Tags: php, input, echo, inputbox

I want to display the input from a input-box text, right beside the input-box if it got data.

I want to use it in our checkout for the customer name.
That when the customer has entered their name, it echo beside it "Hi (customer-name)"

The input-box is on the same page. So the echo needs to be displayed right beside the input-box.

The data needs to be displayed when the customer is not focussing anymore on this input-box. So when it clicks on an other input-box or beside it, it needs to be displayed.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you want the inputbox text on another page? Is it on the same page? Does it need to be updated for every key press? Some more information, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with pure inline javascript, you can attain this using onblur event:

```
<input type="text" value="" onblur="if(this.value !=''){document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML='Hi, '+this.value;}else{document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML='';}" />
<span id='hi'></span>
```

Empty span, or whatever other html place holder will fill with "Hi, (username)" if the input loses focus and is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Javascript, rather than php.

To make it very simple:

```js
function sayHi(){
  var name = document.getElementById("box1").value;
  document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" onblur="sayHi();"><span id="username"></span>
```

Comment: I provided a fiddle snippet. You set the script to onLoad, you need to wrap it in `<head>`. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/kysrp39u/1/